# Why equal probabilities sometimes seem different?

Tags: perception

I was told that's more a psychology question than probability. If for example i throw a dice 4 times and get {3,5,2,1}, i would be less surprised compare to getting {1,1,1,1} even though every permutation has the same probability. Why is that?

Why in real life we would be more suspicious the dice is rigged if we got a "special" sequence than getting something that looks random?

Also, what tags can i add for this question?

Comment: Recognising patterns is necessary for survival. For this reason, we can expect them to stand out, or have more [salience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salience_(neuroscience)).

Answer (score 1):

You should look at Kahneman's [heuristics](https://books.google.fi/books?hl=fi&lr=&id=_0H8gwj4a1MC&oi=fnd&pg=PR8&dq=kahneman&ots=YFj96OU1-H&sig=VEsKP6yCg9LrBNcIa-09oUqDvtI&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=kahneman&f=false) on the topic. We all have deeply engrained a system that takes pleasure in finding surprising situations (for example creating presuppositions on emotional valence) without taking into consideration the factual side of the event. He calls the rational, less used one system 2, and the more intuitive and impulsive one system 1, which is present for most of the time causing cognitive heuristics. We are classically conditioned to take in the more diasporic result as more usual.

As Michael mentioned above. It might have something to do with [gestalt perception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestalt_psychology) also deeply ingrained in our machinery to acquire information.